# Flutter + FlutterFire version solving failed firebase_remote_config with firebase_messaging as per migration guide

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-packages

I have checked many questions like this but not having proper answers so posting again.

I want to use **firebase_messaging** and **firebase_remote_config** together. But It has conflicts with **firebase_core**

**Working Perfect When:**

```
firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

Problem Occurs When I add **firebase_remote_config**:

```
firebase_remote_config: ^0.6.0
```

**Getting Error:**

> Because firebase_remote_config >=0.6.0 depends on firebase_core ^0.7.0
> and flutter_app depends on firebase_core ^0.5.0+1,
> firebase_remote_config >=0.6.0 is forbidden. So, because flutter_app
> depends on firebase_remote_config ^0.6.0, version solving failed.

and If I change the version of the **firebase_core** to the latest, It's giving me the same error for **firebase_messaging**

I had given versions same as [migration](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#2-update-firebase-plugins) guide but not working.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2):

It's basically a problem with `firebase_messaging`. It should depend on the newest `core` package, but it does not (for some mysterious reason). To get the newest info on this, follow https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4650 cause the situation may develop dynamically, but as of 5.02.2021, working solution is to upgrade `firebase_messaging` to `^8.0.0-dev.14` version. It's not stable, so we shouldn't be really happy with that, but we have no other option right now.